# C++ wrappers for execv(3)

Tags: c++, beginner, child-process, overloading, posix

Calling `execv(3)` (and similar functions) in C++ can be
[problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190184). `execv` expects an array of const pointers to
non-const `char`, and string literals are inherently const, so you have
to jump through hoops to convert your literals to non-const char arrays.
And of course in C++ you normally want to use vectors and strings
instead of arrays.

Not finding any standard functions to handle this, I wrote two wrapper
functions to make things easy. They seem to work correctly, *in the ways
I thought to test*, but I’m fairly new to C++; more experienced
developers may see any number of pitfalls I’ve missed.

My first version just used `argv[0]` as the path. Then I checked and
found [good reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315812) for `path != argv[0]` in some cases, so I
overloaded it; one version is more general and one simplifies the call.

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <unistd.h>


int execv_cpp(const std::string &path,
              const std::vector<std::string> &argv);
int execv_cpp(const std::vector<std::string> &argv);


int main()
{
    // Test some failure modes.

    execv_cpp({});
    perror("execv() 1 failed");

    execv_cpp("/bin/ls", {});
    perror("execv() 2 failed");

    execv_cpp({"/foo/bar/baz"});
    perror("execv() 3 failed");

    execv_cpp({"/etc/passwd"});
    perror("execv() 4 failed");

    // Test valid calls.

    if (fork() == 0) {
        execv_cpp({"/bin/ls", "-lart"});
        perror("forked execv() unexpectedly failed");
        return 0;
    }

    usleep(50000);
    execv_cpp("/bin/ls", {"ls", "-lh"});
    perror("final execv() unexpectedly failed");

    return 0;
}


int execv_cpp(const std::string &path,
              const std::vector<std::string> &argv)
{
    /* Convert arguments to C-style and call execv. If it returns
     * (fails), clean up and pass return value to caller. */

    if (argv.size() == 0) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<char *> vec_cp;
    vec_cp.reserve(argv.size() + 1);
    for (auto s : argv)
        vec_cp.push_back(strdup(s.c_str()));
    vec_cp.push_back(NULL);

    int retval = execv(path.c_str(), vec_cp.data());

    int save_errno = errno;
    for (auto p : vec_cp)
        free(p);
    errno = save_errno;
    return retval;
}


int execv_cpp(const std::vector<std::string> &argv)
{
    /* Overloaded. Use first element as path for simpler call. */

    if (argv.size() == 0) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    return execv_cpp(argv[0], argv);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are not by any order of significance.

### Which operating system standard?

A platform supporting C++ does not necessarily have an `execve()` call; that depends on `<unistd.h>`. Are you sure you're not making assumptions about what it contains?

Perhaps you aren't, but you need to double-check and document this.

### Wrapping a single operating system call is questionable

If you've written this for your own use, since you `execve()` all the time like there's no tomorrow :-) ... then ok. Otherwise, developers would probably be hesitant to incorporate a idiosyncratic piece of code which handles exactly one out of dozens of system calls.

Also, even focusing on exec'ing another program, we have:

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
int execle(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
int execvpe(const char *file, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

I'm not saying you need to implement a "Cpp-ified" version of all of these - on the contrary, it would probably be a bad idea - but you chose the less-general version.

### Don't add utility/library functions to the global namespace

Application code uses (or rather, may use) the global namespace; library code uses a dedicated namespace. What you've written is supposed to be used repeatedly, not just once - so it's essentially library code, right? Put it in some namespace (e.g. `util` or `unix` etc.) A benefit of that is that you don't have to append the artificial name extension, i.e. `unix::exec` sounds nicer than `execve_cpp`.

### Confusing parameters in your second variant

If I look at your second variant:

```
int execv_cpp(const std::vector<std::string> &argv);
```

It would not be clear to me whether the element of that vector should be the name of the binary I wish to execute. You may think you're making things more convenient for the client code, but *people would rather type a few more characters than have to contend with semantic ambiguity.*

### If you're Cpp'ifying - do so for errors as well

In C++, passing invalid arguments typically causes an exception to be thrown; and you don't need to return anything, since you never return (as opposed to throwing an exception). Thus, for example:

```
void execv_cpp(const std::vector<std::string> &argv)
{
    if (argv.size() == 0) { 
        throw std::invalid_argument(
            "At least one argument must be provided, being the path of "
            "the binary to execute");
    execv_cpp(argv[0], argv);
}
```

but of course, you're making it easy for the calling code to get it wrong by being willing to take an empty argv in the first place.

### Don't force people to use `std::vector`'s

A vector is just one specific container. There's no reason to assume the calling code is using vectors; and you're not even actually using the vector - you're converting it into a C-style array.

> in C++ you normally want to use vectors... instead of arrays.

Not true. You *sometimes* want to use them.

### Don't force people to use `std::string`s

> of course in C++ you normally want to use... strings...

Sometimes, sometimes not. An `std::string` is just one way - albeit the default way - to represent strings. Remember, it's in the library - it's not int he langue. And `std::string` involves memory allocation policy (stack & heap etc.) which might not be appropriate to everyone. You should be more flexible, e.g. by templating on the string type:

```
template<typename S>
void execv_cpp(const std::vector<S> &argv);
```

or by using [string views](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (C++17, experimental in C++14).

### Consider a C++'ish interface for a bounded number of arguments

If you know the number of arguments at compile time, you can just have the following:

```
template <typename Args...>
void execv_cpp(std::string_view binary, Args&&... arguments);
```

and use `std::to_string()`, or `operator<<` into a stringstream, on each of the arguments in a loop. That gives maximum flexibility to the calling code, and makes `exec()` ing a binary basically the same as calling an arbitrary function:

```
execv_cpp(my_binary, 1, "two", std::optional<int>(3), 4.0);
```

Now, true, in this case you would be using up memory for string conversion results, but in the fixed-number-of-arguments case it's acceptable, I would say.

### No need to duplicate strings

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190208/1593077) you linked to, it specifically says it's safe to const_cast the `char` pointers. So no need for the `strdup()`.

Comment: Thank you. I did specify the POSIX tag; anything POSIX-compliant should include `execve` and friends, no? I agree that wrapping all seven variations would be overkill; I chose to wrap the one that best fits my current project. Haven’t really studied namespaces yet, but will keep that advice in mind; as PEP 20 says, “Namespaces are one honking great idea”. The rest will have to wait until I’m less of a beginner.